# WordPress and GoogleMaps

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I have some Google Maps code worked out to load multiple markers in an ordinary fashion, much like the examples in the Dev section on GoogleMaps site. Works fine as part of a website I have (sault.us). Now I'm trying to embed the same code in a WordPress site page. I'm running into roadblocks, the latest thing I've been told is to try to embed the code via a custom field but WP doesn't recognize the code at all. IS there a sound methodology for doing this or do I give up and try to do this via one of the Google Maps plugins they have? Anyone else run into this?

Comment: You can follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988000/wordpress-adding-google-map

Comment: Thank you Montu but I believe that question was about static maps, my map is more like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps - and when I embed or try to add the code in a custom field it doesn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The official way to add Javascript to WordPress is to use wp_enqueue_script() in your functions.php file.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

Comment: if this was just javascript it would work but my code also has HTML, a div tag followed by the javascript to populate it.

Comment: @axon You'll need to split the HTML from the javascript. you could use a custom HTML element (block if you're using gutenberg editor or just add it in the html flow with the normal editor) to add the div in, and then enqueue the javascript file separately to populate it. Just choose a unique ID for the html element so the javascript doesn't conflict with anything else on your site :)

Comment: That makes sense, next time I have to do this I'll try that route. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Paal. I found another hint about a possible resolution. I ended up creating a custom page template and embedding my code directly in it.

```
<?php
/**
   * 
   * Template Name: CustomMapPage
   *
   */

   get_header(); ?>

 <div id="primary" class="site-content-fullwidth">
  <div id="content" role="main">
 <!-- followed by my code --->
   </div><!-- #content -->
   </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Save this in theme directory as 'CustomPage.php' and choose it as a template. The map now displays.